# Gracenote Entourage license

Tags: gracenote

I have created an entourage application and try to use GN_Entourage_Demo. However, although I placed license infos in to the `GNViewController.m` it gives error like that:

`2013-09-18 13:26:01.682 GN_Entourage_Demo[1583:11f03] getUserACR: ERROR: User Create New: client id '1551360' not supported by current license
2013-09-18 13:26:01.683 GN_Entourage_Demo[1583:11f03] Error: Invalid User`

Answer (score 1):

If 1551360 is your correct client ID, ensure that it is the ID specified in the license that the application is loading.

These should be specified in the GNViewController.m file:

```
/*** Enter your client id, client tag, and license info here ***/
#define CLIENT_ID  @""
#define CLIENT_TAG  @""
#define LICENSE_INFO  @""
```

If 1551360 is *not* the ID that you have defined here, it could be that the application is attempting to load a previously serialized user?  The debugger should be helpful in determining this.